# catching Get-ManagementRole exception on non-existent role

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting, exchange-server-2010

```
try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "...";  #<- tried all settings 
#   $myRole = Get-ManagementRole $CustomRole;  #<- terminates if role doesnt exist 
    New-ManagementRole $CustomRole -UnScopedTopLevel; #<- same if existent
} catch {
    ...   #<- never happens
}
```

I need to create a new custom unscoped role if it is not already existent. My problem is that New-ManagementRole just terminates my script if the role is already existing and that Get-ManagementRole cant be used to check for that role because it terminates my script if that role doesnt exist ^^

Both Cmdlets cant be catched with 'catch' (!!??)

er,…  any suggestions please…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if your tools doesnt work like you need it to work, build
a new tool ;-) …here is some kind of solution:

if (Test-ManagementRole "MyCustomRole" -Single) {...}

```
function global:Test-ManagementRole
{
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Mit Test-ManagementRole wird überprüft, ob eine Management-Rolle existiert und
optional, ob sie einem bestimmten Typ entspricht.
.DESCRIPTION
Test-ManagementRole (by .rhavin;) überprüft die im System vorhandenen Management-
Rollen und liefert die Zurück, die den angegeben Kriterien entsprechen.
.PARAMETER Roles
Objekt-Array der Management-Rollen. Kann als Pipe übergeben werden. Wird dieser
Parameter weggelassen, werden alle im System definierten Rollen überprüft.
.PARAMETER Name
Der Name der Management-Rolle. Es können Wildcards (z.B. '*mail*') verwendet werden.
.PARAMETER Type
Der Typ der Management-Rolle. Es können Wildcards (z.B. '*recover*') verwendet werden.
.PARAMETER Display
Wird dieser Switch angegeben, wird ein ausführlicher Text angezeigt,
ansonsten liefert das Commandlet nur Wahr/Falsch zur weitern Verarbeitung
zurück.
.PARAMETER HideFalse
Wird dieser Switch angegeben, werden nur User, welche zur angegebenen
Rolle gehören, an die Pipeline weitergegeben bzw. angezeigt.
.PARAMETER Single
Wird dieser Switch angegeben, wird der Vorgang bei der ersten Übereinstimmung abgebrochen.
.EXAMPLE
Test-ManagementRole -Name *mail* -Type *im* -Display
Zeigt alle Management-Rollen an, welche 'mail' als Namensbestandteil haben und
in deren Typ 'im' vorkommt.
.EXAMPLE
Test-ManagementRole *Organization* -Single
Überprüft, ob eine Rolle mit dem Namensbestandteil "organization" existiert.
#>

param(
$Name = '*',
$Type = '*',
[switch]$Display,
[switch]$HideFalse,
[switch]$Single,
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$Roles
)

begin {
    if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.PipelinePosition -eq 1)
    {
        $cmd = "Get-ManagementRole | Test-ManagementRole";
        if ($Name) {$cmd += (' -Name "' + $Name + '"');}
        if ($Type) {$cmd += (' -Type "' + $Type + '"');}
        if ($Display) {$cmd += ' -Display';}
        if ($HideFalse) {$cmd += ' -HideFalse';}
        if ($Single) {$cmd += ' -Single';}
        Invoke-Expression $cmd;
        break;
    }
    $colOldTx = $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor;
    $found = $false;
    if ($Display) {Echo "";}
}

process {
    if ($Single -and $found) {return $null;}
    function DoTest
    {
        if ($_.Name -like $Name)
        {
            if ($_.RoleType -like $Type) {return 2;}
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    $mytest = DoTest;   
    if ($mytest -eq 2)
    {
        $found = $true;
        if ($Display)
        {
            $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Green';
            Write-Host $_.Name 'ist vom Typ' $_.RoleType;
            return;
        }
        return $true
    }
    if ($HideFalse -or ($mytest -eq 0)) {return $null}
    if ($Display)
    {
        $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Red';
        Write-Host $_.Name 'ist vom Typ' $_.RoleType;
        return;
    }
    return $false
}

end {
    if ($Display)
    {
        if (!($found))
        {
            $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Red';
            Write-Host "Es wurde keine ManagementRolle mit Namen `"$Name`" vom Typ `"$Type`" gefunden.";
        }
        echo "";
    }
    $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $colOldTx;
}

}
```